# Huawei Location Kit Geofence is throwing Error 10201

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to integrate geofence but having an error as I mentioned on question,

Here is my log:

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uDVD.png)

We checked all the source codes were correct, and it was working before, it happened suddely.

We tried many menthods it was not working.

We checked with the location kit developer, the issue is because of unistall and install apk file for many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your are reaching the limit of geofencing.

[image: description]

For further refference please visit below url where all error codes and their meaning is defined.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/location-error-code